# Need input for URL Template placeholder find and replace function

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Code to find and replace the placeholder in URL template as given below

URL Placeholder like `{cookies:partnumber}`

input

```
 var url = 'http://localhost:3000/product/{cookies:partnumber}/user/{users:userId}';
```

output

```
http://localhost:3000/product/100/user/99
```

Node.js Code

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/product/{cookies:partnumber}/user/{users:userId}';

function parameters(){}

parameters.prototype.getCookies = function(key) {
    return '100';
};

parameters.prototype.getUsers = function(key) {
    return '99';
};


var splitURL = url.split('/');

_.map(splitURL,function(obj, index){

    if(obj.match(/{*}/)){
        var k = obj.split(':');
        var fn = 'get'
            .concat(k[0]
                .substring(1)
                .toString()
                .charAt(0)
                .toUpperCase()
                .concat(k[0]
                    .slice(2)
                )
            ).trim();
        var key = k[1].substring(0,k[1].length-1);
        var p = new parameters();
        if (fn in p && typeof p[fn] === "function") {
            splitURL[index] =  p[fn](key);
        }
    }
});

console.log(splitURL.join('/'));
```

Please suggest, if any other way to implement the same and optimized the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using lodash already, why not use [`_.template`](https://lodash.com/docs#template)?

Comment: _.template is interpolated data properties for that I need to prepare the data before template call. But I need to fetch the data on demand i.e., based on the data pattern need to fetch the value.